# changing position of an object in react with css ,adding it to the above element

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to write a react website and I want to define header and footer in `app.js`

```
  <React.Fragment>
  <Router>
    <Header
        brand="My brand"

        fixed
        color={"transparent"}
      />
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={MainPage} exact />



        <Redirect to="/"  />
    </Switch>
     <Footer style={{"""css styles...""}}/>
  </React.Fragment>
```

the problem is I want to make footer appear in the bottom of the element that comes before it(in this case for example `<MainPage />`), not as a block element in the bottom how can i do that?  should I add something to the `MainPage.js`?

I rather add parameters in place of css styles in footer tag.one more thing is that header works fine and part of the header css looks like this:

```
absolute: {
    position: "absolute",
    zIndex: "1100"
  },
  fixed: {
    position: "fixed",
    zIndex: "1100"
  },
  container: {
    ...container,
    minHeight: "50px",
    flex: "1",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "nowrap"
  }
```

the header css is too long and I hope that this part of css is enough.

Comment: Please, can you clarify what `not as a block element in the bottom` means? Do you mean as a `fixed` block always visible?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as a child:

```js
const MainPageWithFooter = () => <MainPage><Footer style={{/*css styles*/}}/></MainPage>

// ...

<Route path="/" component={MainPageWithFooter} exact />
```

And, in your original `MainPage` component:

```js
return (
  <div class='main-page'> /* Or whatever you have at MainPage*/
    // Your main page stuff
    // ...
    {props.children}
  </div>
)
```

But I suggest you to do a clearer separation between React components and DOM elements: create a new generic `Page` component, which includes its main `<div>`, the footer and the router.

Comment: I think if I pass it as a child , I have to do it for all the pages I define in route ,maybe there is a better way to escape repetition , maybe using pure css.

I think the way I defined in route is very generic itself ,sorry I'm new to react.

Comment: Read the last suggestion: do a better compositing, where outer React components also render outer HTML components, AKA, the `div` where the footer should be in (the one defined in `Main Page`) should NOT be in `MainPage`, but in the component which renders the router,

Comment: Using a CSS trick like adding `margin-top: -200px` to the footer will surely be a bad decision. It's better to write good code than hackish one, which you will probably have forgotten the next year, when you need to do some update to the page.